# Why does this sum converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I know that the following sum converges to 2 via WolframAlpha, but I am not sure why.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \left[\frac{2}{k} - \frac{4}{k+1} + \frac{2}{k+2}\right] = 2$$

WolframAlpha gives the following partial sum formula:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \left[\frac{2}{k} - \frac{4}{k+1} + \frac{2}{k+2}\right] = \frac{2n}{n+2}$$

I would intuitively guess that the result of the partial sum formula is 2 for $n = \infty$. Where did that partial sum formula come from? Can someone help me build some intuition here?

Comment: I suspect telescoping. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\begin{align}k\left(\frac 2k-\frac{4}{k+1}+\frac{2}{k+2}\right)&=2-\frac{4k}{k+1}+\frac{2k}{k+2}\\&=2-4\left(1-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)+2\left(1-\frac{2}{k+2}\right)\\&=4\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: Slick simplification! ^_^

Comment: Can you add some more detail to the second step of the simplification? why can you reduce the 4k/(k+1) and 2k/(k+2) terms like that? I understand how you the end result is equal to 2, but I don't understand the simplification used here.

Comment: @natdempk: Sure. $\frac{4k}{k+1}=4\cdot\frac{k}{k+1}=4\cdot\frac{(k+1)-1}{k+1}=4\left(\frac{k+1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=4\left(1-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$.

Comment: Wow, very clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let the sum of series be denoted by $S$, the term corresponding to each k be $s_k$. Thus each $s_k$ is made of three terms.

$S=\sum s_k=\sum k(\frac{2}{k}-\frac{4}{k+1}+\frac{2}{k+2})$

$=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} (2-\frac{4k}{k+1}+\frac{2k}{k+2})$

Notice that last term of each $s_k$ and first 2 terms of $s_{k+1}$ have a sum $0$ as seen below:  $\frac{2k}{k+2}+2-\frac{4(k+1)}{k+2}=2 +\frac{-2k-4}{k+2}=0$

Taking first two terms of $s_0$ and last term of $s_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity:
$S=\lim_{n \to \infty} (2-\frac{4*1}{1+1}+\frac{2n}{n+2})=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n}{n+2}=2$

Answer (score 1):

You can start by doing the things you *can* do. They don't always help, but doing something is better than doing nothing, and you really should try out all of your leads before you declare yourself stuck on a problem.

One obvious thing that you *can* do is to simply simplify the terms; one such simplification is to combine the fractions. And it turns out that

$$ k \left[\frac{2}{k} - \frac{4}{k+1} + \frac{2}{k+2}\right] = \frac{4}{(k+1)(k+2)} $$

from which the problem is nearly trivial if you're at all familiar with similar examples.